# Relational algebra: if $f^{'}: E/ {\sim} \rightarrow X$ then $f^{'}$ is unique.

Tags: functions, category-theory

Let $E$ be a set, and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $E$, and let $p$ be a projection such that $p : E \rightarrow E/{\sim}$, and $x \sim y$ implies that $f(x)=f(y)$. Then there exists a unique $f' : E/ {\sim} \rightarrow X$ such that $f = f' \circ p$.

Now, there is a proof for the fact that $f'$ is unique, which I am unable to understand. It follows from the fact that $p$ is surjective, and by supposing that there are two distinct functions $g,h$ such that $f = g \circ p = h \circ p$, then $g,h$ are identical on $\mathcal{P}(E)$, thus $g=h$, but I am unable to understand how you can come to this conclusion/

Comment: Notice this typographical difference: $$ E/\sim\to X $$ $$\text{versus} $$ $$ E/{\sim} \to X $$ There is a reason for this: In $x\sim y$ there is a space before and after the binary relation symbol, but in $E/{\sim}$ there should be no such space; i.e. it should not look like $E/\sim$ but rather like $E/{\sim}.$ Coding it as E/{\sim} means that there is nothing before or after the binary relation symbol so that space does not appear. That's the way to do it and I edited the question accordingly. (When I read the question I thought for a second that $\sim\to$ was intended as a binary relation.)

Comment: You want to prove that if $g,h$ are two functions such that $g\circ p=h\circ p=f$, then $g=h$ in other words that for all $\overline{x}\in E/{\sim}$, $g(\overline{x})=h(\overline{x})$. But $\overline{x}\in E/{\sim}$ is of the form $p(x)$ because $p$ is surjective. Then $g(\overline{x})=g(p(x))=f(x)=h(p(x))=h(\overline{x})$. This hold for every $\overline{x}$, so $g=h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try fixing your setup.

1. $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $E$
2. $p\colon E\to E/{\sim}$ is the projection (mapping $x$ to its equivalence class)
3. $f\colon E\to X$ is a map such that, for all $x,y\in E$, $x\sim y$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$

Under these assumptions you want to show that there exists a unique map $f'\colon E/{\sim}\to X$ such that $f=f'\circ p$.

Every element of $E/{\sim}$ is of the form $p(x)$, for some $x\in E$; then
$$
f'(p(x))=f'\circ p(x)=f(x)
$$
and uniqueness of $f'$ follows. Existence is guaranteed by the fact that $p(x)=p(y)$ if and only if $x\sim y$ and, in this case, $f(x)=f(y)$ by assumption.

Comment: I still don't see how the uniqueness of $f^{'}$ follows.

Comment: @JohnMayne If a map $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective and you have $g\colon B\to C$ and $h\colon B\to C$ with $g\circ f=h\circ f$, then $g=h$. Or, within the specific case: if $f''$ is another such map, it must satisfy $f''(p(x))=f(x)$, so $f''(p(x))=f'(p(x))$.